# WSE 3.0 raises WSE1608 error

Tags: web-services

We have a wse 3.0 enabled webservice and some client computers are receiving this wse1608 error message 
WASE1608: No XOP parts were located in the stream for the specified content-id:

Any ideas what would cause this?  It works find on some all but one client in the same office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the WSE 3 Error message, further examination of the error showed that there was a SOAP Fault being returned form the server.